# how to hide soft keyboard when default menu selecting in edit text?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, hide

on my app there is an option to select text from the edit text.the content will automatically set into the edit text.so i put code for hide the keyboard but when I'm trying to select text  by selecting the default  menu, keyboard comes foreground.i tried to block it through manifest file but it is also not working in my device.one thing i noticed that it is working fine in some other devices so what about this?please help me...

code used for hiding the soft keyboard is follows

1)

```
 InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Edittext.getWindowToken(),0);
```

or

xml

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:editable="false">
    </EditText>
```

2)  code used to hide the softkeyboard in particular activity (Manifest file)

```
<activity android:name=".selecttext"  android:label="@string/app_name"  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".selecttext"  android:label="@string/app_name"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for the edittext..

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);      
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)   
{  
    edittext.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);  
    edittext.setTextIsSelectable(true);  
}
```